# Django-rest-framework : create serializer for registration of two diferent user-type foreignkey relation with one custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I want to create two user registration using one custom user.

Here is my
MODELS.PY:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True )
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(_("Phone number"),unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(_("Username"),max_length=254,unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(_("Full Name"), max_length=50, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(_("Birth date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]
```

```
class Aesthete(models.Model):

    basicuser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(_("Verified"), default=False)
```

```
class Artist(models.Model):

    basicuser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(_("Verified"), default=True)
    debutsong = AudioField(upload_to='songsfile', blank=True,
                        ext_whitelist=(".mp3", ".wav", ".ogg"),
                        help_text=("Allowed type - .mp3, .wav, .ogg"))
```

How can I create registration serializer and view? Please help. Thank you.